# Laravel 4 Resource routing error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this route :

```
// work
    Route::resource('work', 'WorkController');
    Route::get('work/{id}/delete', array('as' => 'admin.work.delete', 'uses' => 'WorkController@confirmDestroy'))
        ->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

and my controller **WorkController** is residing at *App/Controllers/Admin*
in the view I call it like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.work.index') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> <br/>Work</a>
```

and I get this error:

```
Error Message: Class App\Controllers\Admin\Work does not exist
```

What is wrong with my code? I have used the same approach for pages, users and menus and it worked.

Comment: what is the namespace of your workController?

Comment: This is my namespace 
namespace App\Controllers\Admin

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm what is the name of controller file in App\Controllers\Admin?. Also your route should be

```
// work
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', function()
{

    Route::resource('work', 'WorkController');
    Route::get('work/{id}/delete', array('as' => 'admin.work.delete', 'uses' => 'WorkController@confirmDestroy'))
    ->where('id', '[0-9]+');
});
```

Comment: name of controller file is WorkController.php @Manoj Saini